# echo odd number between 20 to 1000 and bold the number 23, 33, 43, 63, 193, 213, 333, 453, 693, 793, 813, 883, 963 using php

Tags: php

im newbie with php. i managed to display the odd number. now im stuck with the statement to bold all this number (23, 33, 43, 63, 193, 213, 333, 453, 693, 793, 813, 883, 963)

this is my code so far.

```
for ($i=20; $i<=1000; $i++)

if($i%2 == 1){
        echo $i,


}
```

Comment: What causes you issues ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array to specify the numbers you want in bold:

```
$bold = array(23, 33, 43, 63, 193, 213, 333, 453, 693, 793, 813, 883, 963);
for ($i = 21; $i <= 1000; $i += 2) {
    if (in_array($i, $bold))
        echo "<b>$i</b><br />";
    else
        echo "$i<br />";
}
```

Note by starting on an odd number and incrementing by 2 we can avoid the (`$i % 2 == 1`) test.